How to Add Thermostat to Nest Project
I have created a Nest Project at Nest Console https://console.nest.google.com/device-access/
I want to access my devices from google Cloud Console https://console.cloud.google.com/
I have added the OAuth Credentials from my Google Cloud Console to Nest Console following the tutorial at (https://geoffhudik.com/tech/2023/03/04/trying-google-nest-api-with-postman-and-python/)
When I tried accessing the devices, I got to know that first I need to add device to my nest console.
I am struggling with adding my thermostat to Nest Console. How do I do that ?
What I did is :

Created OAuth Web Application at Cloud Console and copied the client id to nest console
Used Client ID and Secret to Create OAuth Token
Used OAuth Token to access devices via https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/{{project-id}}/devices/
But I got no devices ({})


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the thermostat you have is a Google Nest Thermostat, then you set it up on your Google Account and follow device access documentation.
(https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9893532)
If it is a thermostat that you are building take a look at the cloud to cloud APIs. (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat)
